# Android google play support/unsupport list of devices when Country filter applied

Tags: android, google-play

My application is published in the Google play with country filter as US. So the application is only available for US country. When i check the unsupported devices list, Its displaying lot of devices which should actually support the application. I added every tag in the Manifest to cover almost all the devices from OS version 1.6 and above.Then why these devices are displayed as unsupported devices?

Do the devices which are not available for the US country comes under the unsupported list in the Google play?

Please confirm.

I added below tags in manifest.

```
<supports-screens android:smallScreens="true"
                  android:normalScreens="true"
                  android:largeScreens="true"
                  android:xlargeScreens="true"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.bluetooth" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
All permissions
```

Please find the information that i got when i tried aapt dump badging to this apk

```
package: name='com.xx.xxxx' versionCode='1' versionName='1.0'
uses-permission:'android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE'
uses-permission:'android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE'
uses-permission:'android.permission.CALL_PHONE'
sdkVersion:'4'
uses-permission:'android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE'
uses-permission:'android.permission.CAMERA'
uses-feature:'android.hardware.camera'
uses-feature:'android.hardware.camera.autofocus'
application-label:'XXXXXX'
application-icon-120:'res/drawable-ldpi/appicon.png'
application-icon-160:'res/drawable-mdpi/appicon.png'
application-icon-240:'res/drawable-hdpi/appicon.png'
application: label='XXXXXXX' icon='res/drawable-mdpi/appicon.png'
application-debuggable
launchable-activity: name='com.xx.xxxx.xxx.xxx'  label='' icon=''
uses-permission:'android.permission.INTERNET'
uses-permission:'android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE'
uses-implied-permission:'android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE','requested WR
ITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE'
uses-feature:'android.hardware.telephony'
uses-implied-feature:'android.hardware.telephony','requested a telephony-related
 permission or feature'
uses-feature:'android.hardware.touchscreen'
uses-implied-feature:'android.hardware.touchscreen','assumed you require a touch
 screen unless explicitly made optional'
main
other-activities
supports-screens: 'small' 'normal' 'large'
supports-any-density: 'true'
locales: '--_--'
densities: '120' '160' '240'
```

Unsupported devices due to the manifest settings:

```
Samsung:
Galaxy Tab(SHW-M180K)
Galaxy Tab(SMT-i9100)
Galaxy Tab 8.9(GT-P7300)
Galaxy Tab 8.9(GT-P7310)
Galaxy Tab 8.9(SGH-I957)
Galaxy Tab 10.1(GT-P7500)
Galaxy Tab 10.1(SC-01D)
Galaxy Tab 10.1(SCH-I905)
Galaxy Tab 10.1(SHW-M300W)
Galaxy Tab 10.1(SHW-M380K)
Galaxy Tab 10.1(SHW-M380S)
Galaxy Tab 10.1(SHW-M380W)
Galaxy Tab™ 7.7(SCH-I815)
Galaxy Tab 10.1v(p3)
Galaxy Tab2 10.1(espresso10wifi)
Galaxy Tab™ 10.1(SGH-T859)
Galaxy Tab 7.0 Plus(SGH-T869)
Galaxy Tab 2 7.0 WiFi (espressowifi)

Motorola:
MZ505(Graham)
MZ608(fleming)
MZ616(pasteur)
XOOM(stingray)
XOOM(umts_everest)
XOOM(umts_hubble)
XOOM(wifi_hubble)
XOOM(wingray)
XT303(silversmart_umts)
XT311(XT311)
XT316(XT316)
XT316(dominoq_umts)
XT317(XT317)
XT319(XT319)
XT320(tinboost_umts)
XT389(XT389)
XT389(argonmini_umts)
XT390(XT390)
XT550(ArgonSpin)
XT550(argonspin_umts)
Flyer(flyer)
G1(trout)

HTC:
HTC Desire C(golfu)
HTC Explorer A310b(pico)
HTC Flyer(express)
HTC_P515E(expresskt)
Puccini(puccinilte)
Touch Viva(opal)
```

Do i need to add any thing my Manifest or can i omit the Google play unsupported device list?

Comment: More helpful for this kind of question:  Edit the post to include the output of "adb dump badging YOURAPK.apk" - this includes information that can tell you a lot about what market might be filtering on.

Comment: I had added additional information too. Please assist

Comment: @uvrpavan, may I ask you how did you manage to generate this "unsupported devices list"? I'm looking for such solution for quite a long time, with no luck...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Currently your application requires telephony to be supported by the device (note the "uses-feature" line related to telephony).  For this reason it's not available on a large number of Android tablet devices.

To declare that telephony isn't a *required* feature of your application, set it to not required by adding this line to your manifest:

```
<manifest>
...
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony"
              android:required="false" />
```

That said, for whatever parts of your code use telephony (make calls, etc), make sure they can react properly to devices where that hardware isn't installed, by hiding/disabling the relevant features, etc.

Comment: Is there any way to check this fix with out uploading it in to the market. checking the build supportability for all the devices.

Answer (score 6):

FWIW, I had to add

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" android:required="false" />
```

to get support on the Galaxy Tab2 10.1.